Forgot yaleh viyavo at melavuh malka bentching?
B"H
Generally if one forgets yaleh viyavo in bentching, one only needs to return and say it again if it was in an obligatory meal (like any of the 3 meals of shabbbos), as mentioned in the shulchan aruch.
What about if one forgot it in bentching for a melavuh malka, if one is accustomed to wash? Even if it can be done with fruit, if one actually did it with bread, maybe it would be considered an obligatory meal and require one to repeat it.
Or maybe not?
Would it also make a difference if one ate some fruit on motzi shabbbos before the official bread meal, not necessarily thinking one way or another if it counted as the melavuh malka?

If there's any doubt about needing bread then there would also be doubt about needing to go back.

Forget melava malka, what if you forget yaaleh veyavo at Friday dinner?

The first paragraph sounds like a misunderstanding.

@DoubleAA all 3 meals of shabbbos one needs to return

@Coreof I've never heard that. If you forget reztei then yes, but I've never heard that for forgetting to mention Rosh Chodesh on shabbat. The Shulchan Aruch (188:7) assumes as I do too

@DoubleAA: Going back for yaaleh veyavo on shabbat rosh chodesh is a machloket rishonim (see e.g Tur OC 188). But as far as bottom-line halachah, I have not heard of anyone paskening different to Shulchan Aruch, and saying that that you have to go back.

Firstly, your "example" of having to repeat Benching in parentheses  (like any of the 3 meals of shabbbos) is incorrect.
The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (44:13) says that at Seudas Shlishit one does not need to repeat  if one forgets Retzay or Ya'aleh VeYovoh:

אֲבָל בִּסְעוּדָּה שְׁלִישִׁית, שֶׁאֲפִלּוּ בַּשַׁבָּת אֵינוֹ מְחֻיָּב לֶאֱכוֹל פַּת דַּוְקָא, וּמִכָּל שֶׁכֵּן בְּיוֹם טוֹב, וּבִרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן אֵינוֹ חוֹבַת הַיּוֹם עָלָיו, לָכֵן אֵינוֹ חוֹזֵר לָרֹאשׁ אֶלָּא גּוֹמֵר כָּךְ בִּרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן.‏

Why? Because it's good to eat bread at the 3rd meal but it's not an absolute obligation, as opposed to the 2 first meals.

To answer our original question: The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (44:14) says that one never has to repeat Benching on Rosh Chodesh if one forgets Ya'aleh VeYovoh in Benching.

סעיף יד':
טָעָה בְּרֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ וְלֹא אָמַר יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא, אוֹמֵר בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' אֱלֹקֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם אֲשֶׁר נָתַן רָאשֵׁי חֳדָשִׁים לְעַמּוֹ יִשְֹרָאֵל לְזִכָּרוֹן, וְאֵינוֹ חוֹתֵם (וְאֵין חִלּוּק בָּזֶה בֵּין בַּיּוֹם בֵּין בַּלָּיְלָה) וּבְחֹל הַמּוֹעֵד אִם לֹא אָמַר יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא יֹאמַר בָּרוּךְ אַתָה ה' אֱלֹקֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם אֲשֶׁר נָתַן מוֹעֲדִים לְעַמּוֹ יִשְֹרָאֵל לְשָׂשׂוֹן וּלְשִׂמְחָה אֶת יוֹם חַג (פְּלוֹנִי) הַזֶּה, בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' מְקַדֵּשׁ יִשְֹרָאֵל וְהַזְּמַנִּים. וּבְרֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה אוֹמֵר, בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' אֱלֹקֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם אֲשֶׁר נָתַן יָמִים טוֹבִים לְעַמּוֹ יִשְֹרָאֵל אֶת יוֹם הַזִּכָּרוֹן הַזֶּה, בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' מְקַדֵּשׁ יִשְֹרָאֵל וְיוֹם הַזִּכָּרוֹן. וְאִם לֹא נִזְכַּר עַד לְאַחַר שֶׁהִתְחִיל הַבְּרָכָה שֶׁלְּאַחֲרֶיהָ אֵינוֹ חוֹזֵר לְרֹאשׁ מִשּׁוּם דִּבְרֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ וּבְחֹל הַמּוֹעֵד אֵינוֹ מְחֻיָּב לֶאֱכֹל פַּת דַּוְקָא.‏

Why? Because on Rosh Chodesh Chodesh there is no obligation to eat bread and Bentsch.

why not quote KSA 44:15 , which explicitly addresses the case of rosh chodesh falling on shabbos?

@JoelK - unsure how that helps, since the OP is asking about Melave Malka, not Shabbos. But, yes, that would prove the same point: "אִם אָמַר רְצֵה וְלֹא אָמַר יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא, וְלֹא נִזְכַּר עַד לְאַחַר שֶׁהִתְחִיל הַבְּרָכָה שֶׁלְּאַחֲרֶיהָ, אֵינוֹ חוֹזֵר לְרֹאשׁ, דְּהָא שֶׁל שַׁבָּת אָמַר, וּבִשְׁבִיל רֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ אֵינוֹ חוֹזֵר"
